# I have a question how I could make my discord bot send the same message that I said but in another channel

Tags: node.js

An example I send a message in a channel that message the bot will send to another channel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.